# Can't get "gem" command to work - Why?

Tags: 10.10, ruby, gems

Ubuntu 10.10 here. On the command line, I'm trying to do:

```
gem install railsless-deploy
```

I get this message:

> The program 'gem' can be found in the
>   following packages:  * rubygems1.8  *
>   rubygems1.9.1 Try: sudo apt-get
>   install

So I did: `sudo apt-get install rubygems1.9.1`

I then try the command again: `gem install railsless-deploy`

But the same quoted message appears again. Why? Any help to figure this out?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question applies to Natty (11.04) as well.  The accepted answer from @Mikel also applies to 11.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rubygems1.9.1 is a virtual package that seems to only exist for backwards compatibility.

It installs ruby1.9.1.

ruby1.9.1 provides `/usr/bin/gem1.9.1`.

So, if you want Ruby 1.9.1, you should run `gem1.9.1` instead of `gem`.

Or, if you want Ruby 1.8.x, you should run `gem`.

(In theory, you should be able to run `update-alternatives --config gem` to make `/usr/bin/gem` point to the 1.9.1 version, but this doesn't seem to work.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Mikel. I've used Ruby 1.8 package so that I can simply use gem. This is for Capistrano deployment so, no need to have the latest rail here. Thanks a lot. Really. :)

Comment: After all, I end up installing a new ruby version, and done it "comme il faut". In order to see the sequence of commands used to achieve this, please see question section below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395183/it-seems-that-i-cant-install-capistrano-with-rails-less-why-is-this